# Create Parallax Background with movie Widgets for Scaffold

Tags: flutter, animation

I want to implement multiple circle-shaped widgets with flags (image) inside them, that move slowly in the background when the smartphone gets tilted. Like trapped bubbles. I think it would look really cool for this login screen of my language learning app.

I thought about making the body: Container(), but this is maybe the wrong approach.

The widgets should not leave the phone's screen area. I think the easiest way would be to just create and image with all the flags on it and to put it as the background, but then it wouldn't be animated and less 'cool'.

Thank you.[image: That's the Screen]